# How to safely install Ubuntu on second disk's separate partition of my pc?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have 2 hard disks in my Asus laptop. One is SDD(256gb) **disk0** and other is HDD(1tb) **disk1**. On SDD disk0 Windows 10 is installed and it has no partition. But in HDD disk1 there are 3 partitions. I have created one partition of 100gb to install Ubuntu as dual boot in disk1.

So as my windows is not installed on this disk, is it possible to install Ubuntu on this disk1's partition safely? Will the data of other partition will be affected of this disk1?
I am new to Linux. Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130749/discussion-on-question-by-vikrraal-how-to-safely-install-ubuntu-on-second-disks).